# How can I create a new object from existing values?

Tags: javascript

I have

```
object.name = 'foo';
var value = 'bar';
...
var params = { object.name : 1, value : value};
```

I want a result equivalent to

```
var params = { foo : 1, value : bar };
```

what can I do?

Comment: What have you already tried? BTW, `{ object.name : 1, value : value}` doesn't make much sense. There's also no JSON here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are sometimes called `associative arrays`, since each property is associated with a `string value that can be used to access it.

Try using `[]` to set object property -

```
object.name = 'foo';
var value = 'bar';
var params = { value:value};
params[ object.name] = 1;
```

**Output:-** {value: "bar", foo: 1}